# Sitemap.xml.gz. can I have a compressed file with more than one sitemap in it?

Tags: seo, web-development, sitemap

I've got quite a few sitemaps as my site is quite large.

Is there any way that I can have a compressed with with multiple sitemap files in it ?

I've googled but can't find the answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sitemap.xml.gz. can I have a
>   compressed file with more than one
>   sitemap in it ?

Search engines will ignore a sitemap archive which contains multiple sitemaps.

> Is there any way that I can have a
>   compressed with with multiple sitemap
>   files in it ?

See the [multiple sitemap files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index) topic at sitemaps.org for instructions to create a sitemap index file.